# Where does the build.settings go?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm currently taking a mobile app development course for beginners, and I've got a question. The class wants me to do some stuff with the build.settings file, but I have no idea where to put it. Suppose my project is titled 'Assignment 6.1', and inside is my src folder, and inside there is my main.lua. Does my build.settings go with my code inside main.lua? Is it just in the src folder? I'm using Corona SDK and keep in mind I am a beginner, so give to me in simple terms. Thanks!

Comment: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/07/10/best-practices-for-organizing-projects/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`build.settings` is an optional LUA file, used to define build-time properties of an app, such as:

- Device `Default Orientation`
- Other `Supported Orientations`
- Application `Icons`
- Custom `Fonts` and lots more.

build.settings file should be placed in the project's base directory (ie.: where your `main.lua` resides)

For more information, read: [Project Build Settings](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html)

Keep Coding................. :)